# Load HTTPS url in a UIWebView

Tags: ios, url, https, uiwebview, asihttprequest

I begin iPhone programming and I have big problem I cant resolve.

So, I have a `UIWebview`, I can load **HTTP** url without problems :

```
NSString urlAdress;
urlAdress = @"http://servername";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAdress];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Its work, my page is load in my UIwebView, but when I replace :

```
urlAdress = @"http://servername";
```

by

```
urlAdress = @"https://servername";
```

I have blank screen.

I read its normal, but is there easy method to load https url in my webview ?
I read about `ASIHTTPRequest` but I didnt arrive to implement it.

I just want to load **HTTPS URL**.

Comment: What happens if you load `https://servername` in Safari?

Comment: In safari I can load both "http: //servername" and "https: //servername"

Comment: Is this with a self-signed certificate?

Comment: Yes exactly, its a self-signed certificate !

Answer (score 6):

Try this :

```
- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace {
    return YES;
}


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
    [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
```

Comment: Do I just add this to the UIViewController containing the UIWebView? I'm not quite sure what to do with this.

Comment: These two methods are part of the [NSURLConnectionDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol, so you put them in whichever file is acting as the delegate for your NSURLConnection.

Comment: i was also using a self assigned certificate and it worked with the above implementation.