# Why some Https url are not loading in the WebView?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

Why some https links are not loading the WebView. I can see that some https url are loading perfectly in the safari browser, but when I try to load the same url in the webview, it is not loading. May be because the https has self-signed certificate ?? Can't we load the url in the WebView which has self-signed certificate ?

EDIT:
Now I am able to call

```
- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace 
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge 
{
    [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
```

Still my https url is not loaded in the WebView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace 
{
  return YES;
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
NSArray *trustedHosts = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"mytrustedhost",nil];

if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust]){
    if ([trustedHosts containsObject:challenge.protectionSpace.host]) {
    [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    }
}
[challenge.sender continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
```

Comment: Should I add NSURLConnectionDelegate in the .h file . So far in .h file UIViewController<UIWebViewDelegate> are added.

Comment: Add in .m file. Let me know if any problem

Comment: I have added the two methods in my .m file. I have kept breakpoint,It is not getting called. :(

Comment: I am processing the request using the following code ,NSURL* urlLink= [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    NSURLRequest* request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlLink];
    
    [self.webView loadRequest:request];

Comment: Please check my question again, I have updated my code as you said. Waiting for your reply

Comment: check edited answer and refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122761/ios-5-nsurlconnection-to-https-servers) link

Comment: Am almost there. Thank you so much.I can able to get the NSData and I am displaying those in the WebView. But the thing is it is bypassing the authentication. If I access my https url, it open a dialog box for authentication , but now it is skipping that area. Any idea ?? Please

Comment: Simply adding the canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace and didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge methods , it is not displaying the https page in webview.SO i added the NSURLConnection delegate methods to get the NSData and calling the loadData method. But it is not working properly.

Comment: Looks like the didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge and canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace method is being called then why those are not loaded in the webview. ??

Comment: For your Information, Now those 2 methods are loading my office mail https url (self-signed), which will ask for authentication in the webpage. Thank you. But I do know one https url , which will pop-up a dialog box instead of webpage for authentication. This is not displayed :(