# How to login a server and get page source on objective-c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, httprequest

I am trying to login a server by sending my username and password by POST method by NSURLConnection on objective-c but I get this from my NSLog

NSLog:

```
NSLog:
    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@",string);
```

What it writes to the console:

```
    
    
    404 Not Found
    
    Not Found
    Sorry!The page requested was not found.
```

Why does this happens? Why do I get Not Found page instead of the index page? What do I do wrong? By the way I am trying to connect https not http I don't know does Here is the source code:

```
    @interface ProjectViewController ()
    @property NSURLConnection * urlConnection;
    @property NSMutableData * responseData;

    @end

    @implementation ProjectViewController



    @synthesize responseData =_responseData;

    - (IBAction)LoginButton:(UIButton *)sender {

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = nil;
        request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://loginpage.com"]];

        NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"sid=%@&PIN=%@", @"username", @"password"];
        NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
        [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setTimeoutInterval: 15];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setHTTPBody:postData];

        _urlConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
        [_urlConnection start];



        //[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"LoginComplete" sender:self];
    }




    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
        [self.responseData appendData:data];
        NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"%@",string);
    }

    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
        //Oops! handle failure here
    }
    - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    }

    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
        if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]]) {
            //NSDictionary *headerFields = [(NSHTTPURLResponse*)response allHeaderFields]; //This would give you all the header fields;
            //NSLog(@"%@",headerFields);
        }
    }
    @end
```

What I just recognized is if I put the part of POST request in to comment it prints the page source to the console but of course I can't send my username and password to the server. I just get the login page's source code but I want to get the source code after I login. Actually I want to redirect to another page by using this session.

This part:

```
    NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"sid=%@&PIN=%@", @"username", @"password"];
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setTimeoutInterval: 15];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
```

Answer (score 0):

is the certificate used on the website self signed? did you try to make the request in a webview to see if it works there? not in an nsurlrequest?

try this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122761/ios-5-nsurlconnection-to-https-servers) maybe it will give you some hints.

Comment: Yes the connection works but when I make post request it doesn't work.